# How do I delete from my FormList once the item has been approved but not lose my data from the original table the data comes from?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am new to coding in MS Access VBA:I have a main form my data is collected.  Then another form that forms a list by team that an action needs to be taken by my Admin team.  The other form is a does a list of who has requested a password reset and the action is set to 0.  Once the admin team goes in and completes the action, the action turns to a 1 showing it has been completed and an email is set back to the requester letting them know that the action has been complete.  I need to know how to code the Approval action private sub where once it has been approved, it will be removed from the list but not from the original table from the first form.  But I do not want to see the person in the list anymore show up after it has been approved.  I have tried to set up where the approvals would write to another saved table but was told by someone else in Stack that I did not have to do that.  I have 2 other forms set up similar but they are deleted from the original table because I am storing the data in another table, but that one had an extra step for the users.  This one doesn't have the last step so I am confused on how to write the code to get it to do what I want.  This is all I have in my sub because I am confused how to proceed.  Any suggestions?  Or do I even need the (Sub ProcessApproved) this step below since I have the step above it?

```
Private Sub ApproveNew()
Dim item As Variant
Dim lst As ListBox

    Set lst = Me.lstDMIPasswordResets

    For Each item In lst.ItemsSelected
        If lst.Column(7) = "Assigned" Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Tbl_DMIPasswordResets SET Request_Status = 
        1 WHERE Term_ID = " & lst.Column(0, item) & ";", dbFailOnError
    End If
Next item

lst.Requery

End Sub





Private Sub ProcessApproved()
Dim item As Variant
Dim lst As ListBox
Dim rstNew As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstEmp As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim lngFldCounter As Long
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim lngNewID As Long
Dim strSQL As String

Set lst = Me.lstDMIPasswordResets

 For Each item In lst.ItemsSelected



Next item

lst.Requery


End Sub
```

Here is my table structure:
[The first image is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVN7k.png)

[The second image is my data in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPrsc.png)

SELECT Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.DMI_ResetID, Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.Date_of_DMIPasswordReset AS [Date of Request], Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.NatGen_ID, Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.FirstName, Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.LastName, Tbl_Site.Site_Name AS Site, Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.DMIMSP_ID, Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.NGLS_Email_Address, Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.Additional_Comments, IIf([Request_Status]=0,"Assigned","Completed") AS RequestStatus, Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.ID_FK, Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.Site_FK, Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.Team_Fk, Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.Request_Status
FROM (Tbl_DMIPasswordResets LEFT JOIN Tbl_Site ON Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.Site_FK = Tbl_Site.Site_ID) LEFT JOIN Tbl_Teams ON Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.Team_FK = Tbl_Teams.Team_ID
WHERE (((Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.Team_Fk)=[forms]![FrmDMIPasswordResetList].[cboTeam]) AND ((Tbl_DMIPasswordResets.Request_Status)=[forms]![FrmDMIPasswordResetList].[txtRequest_Status]));

Comment: Deleting records should be rare. Apply filter criteria to listbox RowSource. Edit question to show table structures and sample data.

Comment: What do you mean by appling a filter to criteria to the listbox RowSource?  Do you mean adding something to the query for the list?

Comment: I do not want to delete the data from the original table --I just want it taken out of the list after it is approved (completed) by the Admin so when the query is reran that person is no longer in the list to approve.

Comment: Does your listbox RowRource use a query or SQL statement like: `SELECT field FROM table;`? Use a WHERE clause and restrict the list. Again, provide table structure.

Comment: My Listbox rowsource is a query.

Comment: I added my query to my data above.  What table structure do you want?

Comment: I am confused by what is required. You have query with dynamic status parameter. If you only want to show records where status is not approved then use that criteria. You obviously know how to build queries.